# raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'diagnosis' Please help me why I got KeyError?

Tags: python, image, computer-vision, data-preprocessing

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-c0942f60e879>", line 71, in <module>
    plot_col(1, lambda x: id_to_image(x))

  File "<ipython-input-19-c0942f60e879>", line 64, in plot_col
    for i, (idx, row) in enumerate(df_train.loc[df_train['diagnosis'] == class_id].sample(1, random_state=SEED).iterrows()):

  File "F:\SOFT_INSTALLER\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "F:\SOFT_INSTALLER\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 'diagnosis
```

Code:

```py
df_train = pd.read_csv('D:/Prof.Qaiser/train_images/train.csv')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25, 16))
SEED = np.random.randint(0,100)

print (df_train)

def plot_col(col, id2im, n_cols=6):
    for class_id in range(0,5):
        for i, (idx, row) in enumerate(df_train.loc[df_train['diagnosis'] == class_id].sample(1, random_state=SEED).iterrows()):
            ax = fig.add_subplot(5, n_cols, class_id * n_cols + i + col, xticks=[], yticks=[])
            im = id2im(row['id_code'])
            plt.imshow(im)`enter code here`
            ax.set_title('Label: %d-%d-%s' % (class_id, idx, row['id_code']) )

# display normal image of each class
plot_col(1, lambda x: id_to_image(x))
```

Comment: You've posted an error message and some code. But you haven't asked a question. This is a question-and-answer site about programming, not a debug-my-code-for-me site. Please ask a specific question about programming. See [ask].

Comment: I got the key error in the above code don't know why I get this error.